# How can I add mesh?

Tags: urdf, ros-kinetic, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner, I am making a 4dof custom arm and I am not able to understand how to add mesh objects to the existing links and code for putting the links at right places with respect to meshes? how does it work? please explain?
How can I find custom mesh objects for my arm, if someone has it please provide a link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285664/how-can-i-add-mesh-?/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [urdf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials). The tutorials explain how to add meshes to links.
If you need more specific help, you will have to provide your current urdf and your meshes.

---

Originally posted by [blasalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18941/blasalat/) with karma: 51 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-19**:
Particularly Step 5 here: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-03-19**:
I am having trouble using mesh files in my URDF file. My main doubt is how will I specify the origin, joint origin for a complex mesh object?